# bootstrap-vue table draggable

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, drag-and-drop, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to do on table with draggable rows. I'm using [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) and [vue-smooth-dnd](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/vue-smooth-dnd).

Vue-smooth-dnd `<Container>` and `<Draggable>` are pretty straight to use. I am able to make my rows draggable, but all my `<td>` came to the first column. I can't figured out what I am doing wrong.

My table's code look like this:

```
<template>
  <b-table-simple>
    <b-thead>
      <b-tr>
        <b-th>#</b-th>
        <b-th>Column</b-th>
        <b-th>Column</b-th>
        <b-th>Column</b-th>
        <b-th>Column</b-th>            
      </b-tr>
    </b-thead>
    <b-tbody>
      <Container>
        <MyTableRow
          v-for="row in row"
          :key="row.id"
          :row="row"
        />
      </MyTableRow>
    </b-tbody>
  </b-table-simple>
</template>
```

My row's code:

```
<template>
  <Draggable>
    <b-tr>
      <b-td>{{ row.id }}</b-td>
      <b-td>{{ row.a }}</b-td>
      <b-td>{{ row.b }}</b-td>
      <b-td>{{ row.c }}</b-td>
      <b-td>{{ row.d }}</b-td>        
  </Draggable>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figuered out that <div> can't be used inside table elements, been allowed only inside <td> or <th> elements. I'm implementing it as a list.